# How to use the find command in Java

Tags: java, linux, command

Wanted to know if there is a find functionality in Java. 
Like in Linux we use the below command to find a file :

```
find / -iname <filename> or find . -iname <filename>
```

Is there a similar way to find a file in Java? I have a directory structure and need to find certain files in some sub directories as well as sub-sub directories.

```
Eg: I have a package abc/test/java 
This contains futher directories say 
abc/test/java/1/3 , abc/test/java/imp/1, abc/test/java/tester/pro etc.
```

So basically the abc/test/java package is common and it has a lot of directories inside it which contain a lot .java files.
I need a way to obtain the absolute path of all these .java files.

Comment: You could have a look at [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and [Finding Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)

Comment: Your title would be better as "how to *emulate/implement* (etc) find command in Java", since the answer to how to "use" it would be to invoke it in a subprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **unix4j**

```
Unix4jCommandBuilder unix4j = Unix4j.builder();
List<String> testClasses = unix4j.find("./src/test/java/", "*.java").toStringList();
for(String path: testClasses){
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

pom.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unix4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>unix4j-command</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'org.unix4j:unix4j-command:0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have to re-invent the wheel because library named Finder already implements the functionality of Unix find command: https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-finder/

Comment: Wouldn't this better be a comment?

Comment: @Tichodroma, IMHO no because this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Tichodroma - I tend to agree with Alex here. I think the problem is the question is not really that good, and its eliciting answers like this. But Alex is right - it answers the question - so I really don't want to move against him.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a java 8 snippet to get you started if you want to roll your own. You might want to read up on the caveats of Files.list though.

```
public class Find {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("/tmp");
    Stream<Path> matches = listFiles(path).filter(matchesGlob("**/that"));
    matches.forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private static Predicate<Path> matchesGlob(String glob) {
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.getDefault();
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = fileSystem.getPathMatcher("glob:" + glob);
    return pathMatcher::matches;
  }

  public static Stream<Path> listFiles(Path path){
    try {
        return Files.isDirectory(path) ? Files.list(path).flatMap(Find::listFiles) : Stream.of(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```